# file_downloaded = full_file_size - remaining TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype, pytube

I tried to run this code but it keeps throwing the mentioned error. The problem is definitely in the Progress() function where i am trying to display the progress bar on the screen/button. I tried several things but nothing works. Please Help!
I am Using pytube3, python 3.7

```
from pytube import YouTube
from tkinter import * 
import threading

full_file_size = 0

def progress(stream=None, chunk=None, file_handle=None, remaining=None):
    file_downloaded = full_file_size - remaining
    per = (file_downloaded/full_file_size)*100
    # btn_text.set(f"{per} % Downloading")
    print(f"{per}%") 

def download_stream():
    global full_file_size
    input_url = entry_var.get()
    ob = YouTube(input_url, on_progress_callback=progress)
    strm = ob.streams.first()
    full_file_size = strm.filesize
    # print(type(file_size))
    print(full_file_size/(1024*1024), "MB")
    
    save_path = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\visual programs\\youtube_download"
    print("Your video is downloading")
    
    strm.download(save_path)
    print("Dowload Complete")
    entry_widget.delete(0,END)
    btn_text.set("Download")
    
def continue_thrad():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=download_stream)
    thread.start()
    print('Thread is working')

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x600")
window.title("Youtube Downloader.")

img = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
l1 = Label(window, image=img)
l1.pack()

entry_var = StringVar()
btn_text = StringVar()
btn_text.set("Download")

entry_widget = Entry(window, textvar=entry_var, font=("Verdana, 20"), relief=SUNKEN)
entry_widget.pack(fill=X, padx=20, pady= 10)

b1=Button(window, textvariable=btn_text, font=("Verdana, 20"), command=continue_thrad)
b1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Error says 'full_file_size' is in integer form, and the remaining variable is None. Just take a look at your code and identify why None is getting passed over there.

Comment: _"I tried several things"_ - can you explain what you tried? For example, have you verified that `full_file_size` and `remaining` are what you're assuming they are?

Comment: @Deepak None might be passing because in the parameters i have passed remaining=None.
But it has to be like that since its a standard format for that function. I tried to remove that so that it automatically takes the value from the callback_function but it still throws and error

Comment: Hello guys I actually got what the issue was. In pytube3 the file_handle parameter is not required and the values need not to be None. It ran successfully after that

Answer (score 0):

```
def progress(chunk, file_handle, remaining):
```

above parameter pass in the progress function to solve the issue. [Note: don't pass `None` in parameter]